# Data encodage half UTF8

Tags: php, wordpress, utf-8, xml-rpc

I'm using XMLRPC to migrate posts from an old WordPress blog to a new one. I manage to get the XML data and convert it to an array, but when i print it to my screen, i find that some data is half UTF8 and the rest is not, here is some data :

En commémoration de la journée mondiale des droits des consommateurs célébrée le 15 Mars de chaque année, La Fédération Nationale du E-commerce au Maroc (FNEM) et la Fédération Nationale des Associations de Consommateurs au Maroc (FNAC) organisent chaque annÃ©e sous lâ€™Ã©gide du MinistÃ¨re de l'Industrie, du Commerce, de l'Investissement et de l'Economie numÃ©rique la journÃ©e Nationale des e-consommateurs.

i'm using the header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8').

Comment: "when i print it to my screen" - that is completely ambiguous. Do you mean in a console, web browser, a teletype console?

Comment: i mean the web browser, i use the PHP echo function